# yesod broken packages

Tags: haskell, yesod

On a fresh Haskell install (OSX from Haskell package) I run:

1. cabal install yesod-platform
2. yesod init
3. yesod devel

and the output was:

```
..
..
yesod-static-1.1.2.2 (reinstall) changes: conduit-1.0.2 -> 0.5.6,
crypto-conduit-0.5.0 -> 0.4.3
me2-0.0.0 (new package)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
yesod-platform-1.1.8
http-conduit-1.9.0
yesod-json-1.1.2.1
yesod-test-0.3.5
warp-1.3.7.4
wai-test-1.3.0.4
wai-extra-1.3.2.4
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

Please, what should I do with this?

Comment: Just to be clear, `yesod devel` is the command the causes the error?

Comment: yes - during yesod devel. During the yesod install I couldn't see anything special.

Comment: Normally after `yesod init` there is a `cd <project> && cabal install && yesod devel` or `cd <project> && cabal-dev install && yesod -dev devel`. Is that not working for you?

Comment: I can create the project (without any problem). Then when I want to run it (yesod devel), I'm getting the broken packages info.

Comment: Can you confirm which version of the yesod executable you're using by running `yesod version`?